# Regular Expression Python3---why

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I have written the following python code

```
import re

def get_items():
    text = '''
    <a href="/archive/q-fin">Quantitative Finance</a>
    <a href="/archive/stat">Statistics</a>
    <a href="/help/general">General information</a>
    <a href="/help/support">Support and Governance Model</a>
    <a href="/help/find">Find</a>
    '''
    pattern = re.compile(r'<a href="/archive/(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.S)
    items = re.match(pattern, text).group(1)
    print(items)

get_items()
```

but it does't work,why?

the regular expression as follws:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'<a href="/archive/(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.S)
```

Comment: You have an error somewhere, re.match is probably returning a `NoneType` because no match was found.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct, but you are using the wrong calls to iterate over the machtes. See the corrected version below which uses `pattern.finditer(text)` and `match.group(1)`.

```
import re

def get_items():
    text = '''
    <a href="/archive/q-fin">Quantitative Finance</a>
    <a href="/archive/stat">Statistics</a>
    <a href="/help/general">General information</a>
    <a href="/help/support">Support and Governance Model</a>
    <a href="/help/find">Find</a>
    '''
    pattern = re.compile(r'<a href="/archive/(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', re.S)

    for match in pattern.finditer(text):
        yield match.group(1)

for item in get_items():
    print(item)
```